# Does WSO2 support Single Sign out as well?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

We are looking to adopt WSO2 , Just curious to know whether WSO2 supports Single-Sign Out feature or not. If you can help me to find this answer would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the latest WSO2 IS supports single sign out

https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS580/OpenID+Connect+Single+Logout

Answer (score 0):

Yes, WSO2 IS supports single sign out.

You can refer docs pointed at [1] and [2] for this. Also, you can try out this with samples provided in [3].

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS580/OpenID+Connect+Single+Logout

[2] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS580/Configuring+SAML2+Web+Single-Sign-On

[3] https://github.com/wso2/samples-is